# angular-datepicker doesn't work in ngDialog

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-dialog

I use https://github.com/likeastore/ngDialog and https://github.com/alongubkin/angular-datepicker

And angular-datepicker doesn't work

```
ngDialog.open(
        { //

            template: '<input type="text" pick-a-date="date" is-open="true" placeholder="Select Date" />{{date}}',

            plain: true,
        })
```

But angular-datepicker works well when it iwn't in ngDialog

jsfiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jediserg/jfsuymsv/9/

**Updated** I change angular-datepicker to jquery datepicker and it doesn't work to. But I fix jquery datepicker by setting timeout on creating

```
 window.setTimeout(function () {
                self.dp = $( "#lesson-date" ).datepicker({dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"});        
            }, 100);
```

But what can I do with angular-datepicker and why all the pickers don't work?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle for this? Are there any error logs in the console?

Comment: Just curious, why not use input type="date"? The built in date picker is much better than the angular date picker on mobile devices.

Comment: no errors in console, it just doesn't open popup when i click in input field

Comment: The main target is desktop and type="date" doesn't add nice popup to select date on desktop

Comment: add fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jediserg/jfsuymsv/9/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem.
The thing is, the datepicker is working fine but you can't see it.
The `ngDialog` css-class has a z-index of 10000 and the datepicker let's say only 5000.
If you change the z-index to just 1000 the datepicker should show up. At least that solved the problem for my pikaday datepicker.